# undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, associations

I am getting this error:

> undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass

I have a model Post, here is my PostsController

```
def new
  @post = current_user.posts.build
end

def create 
  @user = current_user 
  @post = @user.posts.build(post_params)
end
```

Comment: can you show your model user.rb and post.rb

Comment: `current_user` is nil, are you sure you are using the right method and the user is logged in?

Comment: Did you put `before_action :authenticate_user!` in the controller? (assuming you are using Devise)

Comment: and ps. you can just use current_user directly, there's no need storing it in a instance var... so just do: `@post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)`

Answer (score 1):

The `current_user` field in your code is not getting set, and has a value of `nil`. Hence, when you try to access `current_user.posts`, it translates to fetching posts for a `nil` class object. As there is no such method for objects of `nil`class, we get an error.